# What is wrong with my swift VideoWriter code?

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I want to generate a mpeg video from a few images (as frames). 
After I finish writing the video file, I tried saving it to Photos, but iOS consider it incompatible:

```
  let compatible = AVAsset(url: video_url).isCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum
  print("COMPATIBILITY", compatible)  // false
```

And then I tried creating an `AVPlayer` to play the video, and the video fails to play. So the video file must be corrupt somehow.

I reviewed my code closely, but couldn't spot the problem. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
class VideoWriter {

var url:URL?
var assetWriter:AVAssetWriter?

init(url:URL) {
    self.url = url
    do {
        try self.assetWriter = AVAssetWriter(url: self.url!, fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4)
    } catch {
        print("Fail to create assetWriter")
    }
}


func writeFrames(frames:[UIImage], finishedHandler:@escaping ()->Void) {
    let settings:[String:Any] = [
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey: 480, //CANVAS_SIZE * 4 / 3,
        AVVideoHeightKey: 360 //CANVAS_SIZE
    ]

    let assetWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: settings)

    self.assetWriter?.add(assetWriterInput)

    let bufferAttributes:[String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB)]
    let bufferAdapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: assetWriterInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: bufferAttributes)
    let frameTime = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    self.assetWriter?.startWriting()
    self.assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: kCMTimeZero)

    // write the frames here

    let mediaInputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "mediaInputQueue")

    var i = 0
    let frameNumber = frames.count

    assetWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: mediaInputQueue){
        while(true){
            if(i >= frameNumber){
                break
            }
            if (assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData){
                let image = frames[i]
                print("writing frame ", i)
                let pixelBuffer = self.newPixelBufferFrom(cgImage: image.cgImage!)

                var time:CMTime
                if i == 0 {
                    time = kCMTimeZero
                } else {
                    let value = i - 1
                    let lastTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(value), frameTime.timescale)
                    time = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, frameTime)
                }

                bufferAdapter.append(pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: time)
                i += 1
            }
        }
        assetWriterInput.markAsFinished()
        self.assetWriter?.finishWriting(completionHandler: {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                print("Completed?", self.assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.completed)
                finishedHandler()
            }
        })
    }

}

func newPixelBufferFrom(cgImage:CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer?{
    let options:[String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey as String: true, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey as String: true]
    var pxbuffer:CVPixelBuffer?
    let frameWidth = 480 //CANVAS_SIZE
    let frameHeight = 360 //CANVAS_SIZE

    let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, frameWidth, frameHeight, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, options as CFDictionary?, &pxbuffer)
    // TODO: throw exception in case of error, don't use assert
    assert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != nil, "newPixelBuffer failed")

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    let pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer!)
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGContext(data: pxdata, width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pxbuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)
    // TODO: throw exception in case of error, don't use assert
    assert(context != nil, "context is nil")

    context!.concatenate(CGAffineTransform.identity)
    context!.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cgImage.width, height: cgImage.height))
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    return pxbuffer
}

}
```

btw. I didn't add audio input, is that necessary for a MPEG file?

Comment: You say you intend to create an MPEG video file.  But you then use AVVideoCodecH264?

Comment: @ElTomato Yes, that is the problem. I thought MP4 is compatible with H.264 encoding... Stupid mistake. After changing to `AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie`, everything works. Thanks! If you are willing to add an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: No, that's not necessary.  Don't worry about it.  I just read topics here to train my brain out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59351709/5287058

I have same kind of issue can you guys help me??